# How to build maven project on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

I have a JavaFx maven project which I develop on a Windows 10 machine but later will use on a Raspberry pi 4 with the latest raspbian os. I had developed now until a specific state of my application and wanted to test it on my pi now. I have the latest liberica Jdk 15 installed on my pi but I am getting an error which I dont understand:

```
**OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_es2.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_es2.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_es2.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_es2.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_es2.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)**
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2407)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:747)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:214)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:194)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:135)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:53)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:69)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2407)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:747)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:214)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:194)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:135)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:53)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:273)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

And another thing is even though I installed liberica and set it in my project if I run java --version I am getting this print:

```
openjdk 15 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15+36)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 15+36, mixed mode)
```

Can someone maybe tell me wht my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

How did you build the .jar ?

Some tools, for example the shade plugin don't create a cross platform jar.

This would explain the exception: `can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform`

```
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: /home/pi/.openjfx/cache/15/libprism_sw.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64 .so on a ARM platform)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
```